# Trabalhar com som em .NET

Tags: .net

Em .NET é relativamente fácil e simples trabalhar com imagens. É possível por utilizar a classe `System.Drawing.Bitmap` para abrir imagens nos formatos Bitmap, Jpeg e PNG e brincar com seus pixels. O código abaixo, por exemplo, recebe uma imagem qualquer e retorna sua representação em tons de cinza:

```
public void RemoverCores(Bitmap input)
{
    Bitmap output = new Bitmap(input.Width, input.Height);

    for (int i = 0; i <= input.Width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= input.Height; j++)
        {
            Color cores = input.GetPixel(i, j);
            int media = (cores.R + cores.G + cores.B) / 3;
            output.SetPixel(j, j, Color.FromArgb(media, media, media));
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Eu aprendi na faculdade que **imagens e sons são apenas duas formas distintas de sinais de natureza semelhante**, e que **os algoritmos que se aplicam a uma forma também se aplicam a outra**.

Por exemplo, o mesmo algoritmo que "borra" uma imagem serve para remover ruídos de uma faixa de áudio. Simplesmente utilizamos tempo ao invés de altura e largura quando tratamos um som ao invés de uma imagem e, se bem me lembro, ao invés de faixas de cores temos faixas de frequências sonoras.

Na faculdade fazíamos isso com Matlab. No entanto eu gostaria de trabalhar com sons em .NET, com C#. Existe alguma API embarcada ou oficial para isso? Se não existe, ao menos existe algum projeto com o qual eu possa pelo menos gerar e manipular um arquivo .wav ou .mp3?

Answer (score 1):

Eu não sei que tipo de manipulação você vai precisar fazer, infelizmente não vai existir nenhuma função "semi-pronta" igual temos com o Matlab, no Matlab tudo é muito simples, se desejamos criar um filtro (IIR) para remover ruídos observados em determinadas faixas de frequências é possível geral os coeficientes da transferência de função com uma simples linha de código e depois aplicar o filtro no áudio utilizando os coeficientes ...

Antes de efetuar qualquer tipo de manipulação vai ser preciso utilizar alguma lib que seja capaz de decodificar sons (wav, mp3, etc), conheço essas duas e funcionam bem:

[Alvas](http://www.alvas.net/alvas.audio.aspx)

[Naudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio)

Abra seus arquivos utilizando alguma classe que decodifique seu arquivo de áudio, geralmente você terá os valores decodificados em vetor (áudio em mono) ou matriz (áudio em stereo) e manipule da maneira que achar necessário...

PS: Consigo contar nos dedos técnicas de manipulação de imagens que são reutilizadas em áudio, as mais comuns são os filtros e interpolações, os filtros são realmente semelhantes como você falou, a interpolação em imagens são usadas para mudar (alterar) o tamanho de uma imagem tentando manter a melhor qualidade possível, existem diferentes técnicas de interpolação para isso, a mais simples "interpolação linear" é utilizada para repetir ou omitir pixels de uma imagem (esticar ou diminuir) em áudio a mesma técnica é utilizada para alterar a velocidade + frequência do áudio (deixar a fala rápida com som de esquilo ou deixar a fala lenta com voz de demônio)

Comment: Acho que o Naudio vai me ajudar.